# PHP magic getter by reference and by value

Tags: php, getter-setter

I have this class:

```
class Foo {

   private $_data;

   public function __construct(array $data){
       $this->_data = $data;
   }

   public function __get($name){
       $getter = 'get'.$name;
       if(method_exists($this, $getter)){
           return $this->$getter();
       }

       if(array_key_exists($name,$this->_data)){
           return $this->_data[$name];
       }

       throw new Exception('Property '.get_class($this).'.'.$name.' is not available');
   }

   public function getCalculated(){
      return null;
   }
}
```

Where `getCalculated()` represents a calculated property.

Now if I try the following:

```
 $foo = new Foo(['related' => []])
 $foo->related[] = 'Bar'; // Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect

 $foo->calculated; // ok
```

But if I change the `__get()` signature to `&__get($name)` I get:

```
 $foo = new Foo(['related' => []])
 $foo->related[] = 'Bar'; // ok

 $foo->calculated; // Only variables should be passed by reference
```

I'd quite like to return `$data` elements by reference and getters by value in my `__get()`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggest, you need to return a variable from your getter:

```
class Foo {

   private $_data;

   public function __construct(array $data){
       $this->_data = $data;
   }

   public function  &__get($name){
       $getter = 'get'.$name;
       if(method_exists($this, $getter)){
           $val = $this->$getter();  // <== here we create a variable to return by ref
           return $val;
       }

       if(array_key_exists($name,$this->_data)){
           return $this->_data[$name];
       }

       throw new Exception('Property '.get_class($this).'.'.$name.' is not available');
   }

   public function getCalculated(){
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Magic! Thanks, I thought I'd tried this.. but obviously messed it up somehow.